# Clone and remove content as the value of an input changes

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to take an existing `div` and clone it each time the user inputs text into a given text box. When the text has been removed from the input, I'd like for all clones to be removed.

```
<div class="must_be_cloned">
   <label for="company_name"> Company Name </label>
   <input type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="When writing text add new input" />
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly your problem and what to do?

Comment: I've edited your question to what I honestly believe is what you were trying to ask. If I messed up, let me know. You were about to get ripped apart for both a sh**y question, and 0 effort.

Comment: I what like in this webpage (http://www.onlinecvgenerator.com/)... go to this web page... for example when u write information in INPUT of EDUCATION they clone FORM agine... Sorry 4 my English if u can't understand :(

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zprccsyp/5/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('input', '.company-name', function () {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $('.cloned').remove();
    } else if(this.value.length == 1){
        var $newDiv = $(this).closest('.must_be_cloned').clone();  
        $newDiv.find('.company-name').val('');
        $newDiv.addClass('cloned').appendTo('#wrapper');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="must_be_cloned">
        <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="company-name" name="company_name" placeholder="When writing text add new input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it's add many times and with text inside INPUT. I just want new DIV with LABEL and INPUT inside.

Comment: I what like in this webpage (onlinecvgenerator.com)... go to this web page... for example when u write information in INPUT of EDUCATION they clone FORM agine... Sorry 4 my English if u can't understand :(